# Source Code for Eigen-Analysis in GEE using .eigen()?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have been performing a PCA in Earth Engine for some time now, but I am having some trouble with the .eigen() call available in the API. Specifically, I am noticing some inconsistencies in the signs of the eigenvectors which are calculated by the function. If I run the same analysis in Numpy, I get back the exact same values with some rows having flipped signs when compared to the EE side function (it's not a matter of multiplying the array by -1, because some of the signs match and some are inconsistent).

Does anyone know where I can access the source code for this GEE function?

I'd like to see how the eigenvectors are being calculated. I've looked on Github, but I'm not seeing any reference to the underlying structure of this function. It will go a long way to helping me determine how to proceed in my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the eigen function states: *This implementation uses DecompositionFactory.eig() from https://ejml.org*, so the source code, modulo any version differences, is here: https://github.com/hamedrab/efficient-java-matrix-library/blob/master/src/org/ejml/factory/DecompositionFactory.java#L178

However, eigenvectors, by definition, don't have a fixed sign.  Any multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector, including negative multiples.  See this thread (and the many like it): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154716/pca-eigenvectors-of-opposite-sign-and-not-being-able-to-compute-eigenvectors-wi